# Azure Cache Dependency

Tags: caching, azure

I've got two web applications running in Windows Azure, an admin site and a front-end (readonly) site.

The applications don't share the same domain model so I'm not really looking to share the cache between the two. However, since both applications share the same SQL Azure database, I do need some kind of distributed cache breaker, such that updates made in the admin site, will invalidate the cache used by the public site.

I was hoping for a blob implementation of a System.Runtime.Caching.ChangeMonitor but have not had much luck finding one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a custom file monitor for Azure blob storage. Full details [on my blog](http://ben.onfabrik.com/posts/monitoring-files-in-azure-blob-storage).

Answer (score 1):

The AppFabric Caching Service?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278356.aspx